# Сервер возвращает "Method \"PATCH\" not allowed."

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

При патч запросе на http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/any_username/ возвращает

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"PATCH\" not allowed."
}
```

Урлы

```
v1_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
v1_router.register('auth/signup', SignUpViewSet)
v1_router.register('auth/token', TokenViewSet)
v1_router.register('users', UsersListViewSet)
v1_router.register(r'^users/(?P<username>\w+)', AdminViewSet,
                   basename='users/<username>')
v1_router.register('users/me', ProfileViewSet, basename='users/me')

urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/', include(v1_router.urls)),
]
```

Вьюсет

```
class AdminViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin,
               viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = AdminSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
    pagination_class = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

Сериалайзер

```
class AdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name',
                  'last_name', 'bio', 'role')
        model = User
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в Ваше представление метод patch следующим образом:

```
class AdminViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin,
               viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = AdminSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
    pagination_class = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(username=self.kwargs['username'])
    
    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

В соответствие с [документацией](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin), класс UpdateModelMixin предоставляет метод partial_update, который вы можете использовать для обработки PATCH запросов.